# How to Handle token prices for conversion ratio building a oracle contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, oracles, floating-point

I am building a simple **Oracle contract** to provide conversion ratio to an other contract (a simple DEX), where conversion from `token1` to `token2` is fine since it **equals to 10**.

> The problem is when conversion from token2 to token1 since its **result** would be **0.1**.

How should I handle this issue properly ? I am using the following code below:

```
contract Oracle is Ownable {
    uint256 priceTKN1 = 0.01 ether;
    uint256 priceTKN2 = 0.001 ether;

    function updatePriceTKN1(uint256 _newPrice) public onlyOwner {
        priceTKN1 = _newPrice;
    }

    function updatePriceTKN2(uint256 _newPrice) public onlyOwner {
        priceTKN2 = _newPrice;
    }

    function getPriceTKN1() public view returns (uint256) {
        return priceTKN1;
    }

    function getPriceTKN2() public view returns (uint256) {
        return priceTKN2;
    }

    function getConversionTKN1toTKN2() external view returns (uint256) {
        return (priceTKN1 / priceTKN2);
    }

    function getConversionTKN2toTKN1() external view returns (uint256) {
        return (priceTKN2 / priceTKN1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should express the number with a decimal. For example you can fix 8 decimals in the contract, and the number `0.1` would be returned as `10_000_000`. Of course the users/contracts that interact with your oracle need to be made aware of the decimal value.

```
contract Oracle is Ownable {
    uint256 priceTKN1 = 0.01 ether;
    uint256 priceTKN2 = 0.001 ether;
    uint256 constant private DECIMALS = 8;

    function updatePriceTKN1(uint256 _newPrice) public onlyOwner {
        priceTKN1 = _newPrice;
    }

    function updatePriceTKN2(uint256 _newPrice) public onlyOwner {
        priceTKN2 = _newPrice;
    }

    function getPriceTKN1() public view returns (uint256) {
        return priceTKN1;
    }

    function getPriceTKN2() public view returns (uint256) {
        return priceTKN2;
    }

    function getConversionTKN1toTKN2() external view returns (uint256) {
        return (priceTKN1*(10**DECIMALS) / priceTKN2);
    }

    function getConversionTKN2toTKN1() external view returns (uint256) {
        return (priceTKN2*(10**DECIMALS) / priceTKN1);
    }

    function decimals() external view returns (uint256) {
        return DECIMALS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fixed point numbers are not fully supported by Solidity yet. They can be declared, but cannot be assigned to or from.](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#fixed-point-numbers)

Since your oracle may be used by a contract that for example implemented with uint256, I would recommend going with the more traditional approach to represent prices in `uint256`. Prices can change to numbers like 11/3 which would be better represented as 11 * 1e18 * 1e18/ 3 * 1e8. And you will save n conversion to `uint256` for other contracts that you your oracle.

You can always round the number off-chain if you need it like 3.67 instead of 3.66666666667 * 1e18.Web3.js/ethers.js libraries have tooling for that already